# Mahler polynomials and zeros of the incomplete gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, complex-analysis, polynomials

The Mahler polynomials are presented in [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MahlerPolynomial.html), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler_polynomial), and the OEIS ([A08299](http://oeis.org/A008299)). There are rich connections to several areas of analysis and statistical physics, including the Whitehouse simplicial complexes, phylogenetic trees, tropical Grassmannians, and the combinatorics of Lagrange inversion through OEIS [A134991](http://oeis.org/A134991) and [A134685](http://oeis.org/A134685), so I'm curious how Kurt Mahler used them in his [1930 monograph](http://zbmath.org/?format=complete&q=an:56.0310.01) "Über die Nullstellen der unvollständigen Gammafunktionen.", Rendiconti Palermo (in German), 54: 1–41, on the zeros of the [upper incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) (the Cinderella function of Tricomi, which has rich links in calculus and operator theory). (I have no access to Mahler's monograph.)

Can someone sketch the use of these polynomials in Mahler's monograph?

Comment: There are some mentions of the ideas here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042702005538

Comment: @Alex R., thank you. Precisely some relations I expected to find are in the paper. Still, I'm not sure how the results are applied to characterizing the zeros.

Comment: The MO user José Hdz. Stgo gave the link http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/mahler/collected.html#1920s where Mahler's 1930 monograph is available under the year 1927.